# Delete All Subscibers from Marketing Cloud Org

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber

I have 4 lakh subscibers in all subscribers list in marketing cloud instance. I want to delete all subscibers from all subscibers list. As there is no option to export all subscibers once to a list in all subscibers list. So the last option is to use sql query.
Can anyone suggests me that query through which i can delete all subscribers in all subscibers list.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

**IMPORTANT:** If this is a production Marketing Cloud account that has been used to send to consumers, ensure you have read and understand the [Contact Deletion Best Practices](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_best_practices.htm&type=5) article. Make sure you are aware of the potential implications of what you are considering before proceeding. You will be deleting all the preference and unsubscribe information, also.

From the top level administrative business unit, use the _Subscribers data view to populate your data extension:

```
SELECT 
    SubscriberKey,
    EmailAddress
FROM
    _Subscribers
```

Then follow the [Contact Deletion instructions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_delete_contact.htm&type=5).

Comment: i have applied above query in sql query activity when i'm clicking next. It is forcing to select data extension but i need to delete from all subscibers list

Comment: find the screenshot clipped with question

Comment: Sure. You need to create the data extension first. Two fields - SubscriberKey (Text 254) and EmailAddress (Text 254). The DE should be sendable - relates to subscriber on SubscriberKey = SubscriberKey.

Comment: but that will delete from that DE only. How can i delete from all subscibers list

Comment: No. It expunges the contact's data from all backend tables, sendable data extensions, All Subscribers... As per GDPR, it implements the right to be forgotten and nukes all the data you have on the contact, including their bounce and unsubscribe history.

Comment: Thanks @Macca for your support.